# Ruby: convert curl command into Ruby net/http request

Tags: ruby, net-http

I'd like to convert this command line curl command into a Ruby net/http request:

> curl -u user:pword --insecure -XGET
>   "https://192.168.10.10:3000/_search/template?pretty=true" -H
>   'Content-Type:application/json' -d'{"id":"search_template_services",
>   "params":{"environment":"prod","start_time":"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","end_time":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","cantons":["AG"],"service":"WMS","request":"getmap"}}'

my attempt:

```
endpoint = 'https://192.168.10.10:3000/_search/template/?pretty=true&id=search_template_services&environment=prod&start_time=2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&end_time=2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&cantons=AG&service=WMS&request=getmap'

puts "url: #{endpoint}"
uri = URI(endpoint)

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https',
                verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.basic_auth('user', 'pword')
  @response = http.request request
end

data = JSON.parse(@response)
```

But I'm getting the error:

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/json/common.rb:156:in `initialize': no implicit
>   conversion of Net::HTTPBadRequest into String (TypeError)

Apparently the URL isn't correct. If I use the curl it works.

How to fix the net/http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a web site that converts many (not all) curl commands to Ruby:

http://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby

I ran your curl command through this.  The generated Ruby code appears to run, but since it contacts a private server I cannot fully test it.  Here is the code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require 'openssl'

uri = URI.parse("https://192.168.10.10:3000/_search/template?pretty=true")
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
request.basic_auth("user", "pword")
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.body = JSON.dump({
  "id" => "search_template_services",
  "params" => {
    "environment" => "prod",
    "start_time" => "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end_time" => "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "cantons" => [
      "AG"
    ],
    "service" => "WMS",
    "request" => "getmap"
  }
})

req_options = {
  use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
  verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

# response.code
# response.body
```